# Using of standalone model in Catalyst - calling of general methods

Tags: perl, catalyst

I am following receipt of using standalone models in Catalyst in the advent calendar from 2012 here:

http://www.catalystframework.org/calendar/2012/15
and previous days ....

Following this receipt I am transferring existing code from current fat model. I want to have some methods in Model on general level - I expect to put them in this example into `lib/StandaloneApp3.pm` file (eg. create order means to create record in table order_header, table order_item and table log) and call them from Controller with code:

```
$c->model('DB')->create_order($params);
```

I am getting error:

> "Can't locate object method "create_order" via package
>   "WebApp::Model::DB"

When calling function from StandaloneApp3 namespace, this work:

```
&StandaloneApp3::create_order($params);
```

I do not think this is good approach as my Controller should connect only to Catalyst Model and not directly to standalone library.

Is there an error in my code to access methods in StandaloneApp3.pm or when using DBIC::Schema I am not expect to call this method? In case I am not supposed to call methods in StandaloneApp3.pm, what is the correct place were to store methods that can write to more tables in one transaction? Any example also for exact calling those methods from outside Catalyst - eg. from command line?

Thank you for your explanation and example.

----------- ADDED CODE -------------

Catalyst model: 
file: lib\WebApp\Model\DB.pm:

```
package WebApp::Model::DB;
use strict;
use base 'Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema';
1;
```

Standalone Model:
file: lib/StandaloneApp3.pm

```
use utf8; 
package StandaloneApp3;
use Moose; 
use MooseX::MarkAsMethods autoclean => 1; 
extends 'DBIx::Class::Schema';
PACKAGE->load_namespaces;
sub create_order {
    # in development 
    return "order_created"; 
}
PACKAGE->meta->make_immutable(inline_constructor => 0); 
1;
```

Config:
file: webapp.conf

```
<Model::DB>
    schema_class StandaloneApp3
    <connect_info>
        dsn dbi:SQLite:__path_to(data,database_file2.db)__
    </connect_info>
</Model::DB>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please include the code of the model. In particular the top of the file with the package definition and that sub you're calling.

Comment: I have added the code to main post

Comment: It looks correct. Try to get rid of the `use base` and do `use Moose; extends 'Catalyst...'` instead.

Comment: Maybe I did not get it correctly, I have deleted in Model DB `use base 'Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema';`
and added `use Moose;
extends 'Catalyst';`, but I still the same error "Can't locate object method "test" via package "WebApp::Model::DB"

Comment: I meant `extends 'Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema';`. That's more or less the same, but you want Moose to do the subclassing. Catalyst is using Moose internally too. But it really shouldn't make a difference. Something else must be wrong.

Comment: @simbabque, is a code from Catalyst Advent Calendar [link](http://www.catalystframework.org/calendar/2012/15) - WebApp-0.09.tar.gz running in your environment? This code I have used for my example. Just please add a method "create_order" to lib/StandaloneApp3.pm and call it from Catalyst Controller? Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm going to try now. Not sure if I can get it to work in my Windows machine though.

Comment: After installing a load of dependencies into my out of date ActivePerl I managed to reproduce your error.

Comment: I've updated my answer. My initial assumption was incorrect. I did miss something which you did wrong. But it's working now, and it only took about an hour of installing stuff and 20 minutes of playing around. :)

Comment: BTW, don't call subs with `&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `StandaloneApp3` as your *schema class* inside of the catalyst model `WebApp::Model::DB`. That means it's the DBIx::Class schema that is automatically loaded for you. The schema is something like a database object.

To access the schema, you use the `schema` accessor method on the model.

```
$c->model('DB')->schema;
```

So to reiterate, the schema is **not** part of the model. The model does not inherit from the schema. It just [*has* the schema as an attribute](https://metacpan.org/source/GBJK/Catalyst-Model-DBIC-Schema-0.65/lib/Catalyst/Model/DBIC/Schema.pm#L460).

Therefore the method `create_order` in the schema class `StandaloneApp3` is not a method on the model `WebApp::Model::DB`. It's a method on its `schema` attribute.

```
$c->model('DB')->schema->create_order;
```

The easiest way to patch that through would be to make a method `create_order` in `WebApp::Model::DB` that calls the method with the same name on the `schema`.

```
package WebApp::Model::DB;
# ...

sub create_order {
    my $self = shift;

    return $self->schema->create_order(@_);
}
```

I `shift`ed out the `$self` so I can pass on the rest of the argument list `@_` to `$self->schema->create_order`.

To prove this works, I wrote `create_order` in `StandaloneApp3` like this:

```
package StandaloneApp3;
# ...

# You can replace this text with custom code or comments, and it will be preserved on regeneration

sub create_order {
    # in development

    warn "creating order...";
    return "order_created"; 
}
```

I put the `warn` in so we can find it in the log that you have in your console later. Note how it's placed underneath DBIC's comment, because we don't want it to be overwritten if we need to regenerate the schema class later in case someone made changes to the database schema.

Finally I'm calling the model method from `sub index` in the `Root` controller.

```
sub index :Path :Args(0) {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

    $c->model('DB')->create_order;

    # Hello World
    $c->response->body( $c->welcome_message );
}
```

If you now request `/` in your browser (for me that's http://localhost:5000/) now it works, and shows up in the log. Mine is on Windows so it looks a bit odd.

```
[info] *** Request 1 (0.143/s) [8012] [Sun Nov 27 16:25:59 2016] ***
[debug] Path is "/"
[debug] "GET" request for "/" from "127.0.0.1"
creating order... at lib/StandaloneApp3.pm line 23.
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Nov/2016:16:25:59 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5477 "-" "Mozill
a/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0
.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
[debug] Response Code: 200; Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8; Content-Leng
th: unknown
[info] Request took 0.012028s (83.139/s)
.------------------------------------------------------------+-----------.
| Action                                                     | Time      |
+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| /index                                                     | 0.000545s |
| /end                                                       | 0.000340s |
'------------------------------------------------------------+-----------'
```

---

But of course if you have a couple of those methods you want to patch through, it gets a bit tedious to write all of them yourself. You could use AUTOLOAD to create methods on the fly, but that seems wrong in this situation, so I'm not going to explain that.

Instead, let's use [Catalyst::TraitFor::Model::DBIC::Schema::SchemaProxy](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::TraitFor::Model::DBIC::Schema::SchemaProxy), which is a model trait that's [included with Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema#traits) for exactly this situation.

You load it from the configuration file or inside the `__PACKAGE__->config(...)` in your code. I prefer it there, because it's easier to see what's going on when reading the code, and you can still overwrite it later in the configuration files.

Here is the full `WebApp::Model::DB` file. I removed the method `create_order` we put there in the example above, and included the trait configuration instead.

```
package WebApp::Model::DB;
use strict;
use base 'Catalyst::Model::DBIC::Schema';

__PACKAGE__->config(
    traits => 'SchemaProxy',
);

1;
```

That's all you need to change. If you restart the app and request the root `/` again, it will still work.

```
[info] *** Request 1 (0.111/s) [6160] [Sun Nov 27 16:43:45 2016] ***
[debug] Path is "/"
[debug] "GET" request for "/" from "127.0.0.1"
creating order... at lib/StandaloneApp3.pm line 23.
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Nov/2016:16:43:45 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5477 "-" "Mozill
a/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0
.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
[debug] Response Code: 200; Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8; Content-Leng
th: unknown
[info] Request took 0.011867s (84.267/s)
.------------------------------------------------------------+-----------.
| Action                                                     | Time      |
+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| /index                                                     | 0.000712s |
| /end                                                       | 0.000370s |
'------------------------------------------------------------+-----------'
```

I suggest you take a few minutes and read the CPAN pages of the modules I linked in this answer. I just did the same. Catalyst can become very complex underneath and it's hard to remember all of it even if you use it a lot, so freshening up on the docs once in a while is a good idea.

Comment: that was a great analyse on your side, thank you for your efford and time. Model trait `Catalyst::TraitFor::Model::DBIC::Schema::SchemaProxy` I did not know, it helped in this case. I have correct it also in my code and works as expected.

Comment: @Tony glad it helped. I just don't use Catalyst in my free time usually, so it took some time to set it up. ;)